# Countdown in javascript, database and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I need to create a countdown, display it to the user and then when certain time passes, I need to change status field from 1 to 0 in a database. What is the best way to do this?

I wasn't precise enough, sorry about that.  I know how to make ajax request and how to update a DB value, the problem is, how to get the timestamp value from database and use it in JS?

Comment: There are a lot of parts to answer your question. It might be best to split your question into smaller parts. One question about how to make a countdown in JS. One about making an AJAX request. One about updating a DB value.

Comment: @DrRoach I wasn't precise enough, sorry about that.  I know how to make ajax request and how to update a DB value, the problem is, how to get the timestamp value from database and use it in JS?

Comment: Thanks for clearing up your question a bit, I hope my answer below helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a route in PHP which can be called by AJAX to set the status in your Database.

If your route works you can implement the countdown in JavaScript with the help of `setInterval(...)`.
[Example on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp)

When the countdown has finished, call your route with AJAX (within your `setTimeout` callback).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass your value from PHP to JS. You can do this like so:

```
echo "<script>var timestamp = " . $timestamp . ";</scrpipt>";
```

In your PHP script. You can then use your timestamp value in your JS script and create your countdown and fire off an AJAX request when required.